# computing z-scores for 2D matrices in scipy/numpy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, machine-learning, scipy

How can I compute the z-score for matrices in Python?

Suppose I have the array:

```
a = array([[   1,    2,    3],
           [  30,   35,   36],
           [2000, 6000, 8000]])
```

and I want to compute the z-score for each row.  The solution I came up with is:

```
array([zs(item) for item in a])
```

where zs is in scipy.stats.stats.  Is there a better built-in vectorized way to do this?

Also, is it always good to z-score numbers before using hierarchical clustering with euclidean or seuclidean distance?  Can anyone discuss the relative advantages/disadvantages?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

scipy.stats.stats.zs is defined like this:

```
def zs(a):
    mu = mean(a,None)
    sigma = samplestd(a)
    return (array(a)-mu)/sigma
```

So to extend it to work on a given axis of an ndarray, you could do this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats.stats as sss
def my_zs(a,axis=-1):
    b=np.array(a).swapaxes(axis,-1)    
    mu = np.mean(b,axis=-1)[...,np.newaxis]
    sigma = sss.samplestd(b,axis=-1)[...,np.newaxis]
    return (b-mu)/sigma


a = np.array([[   1,    2,    3],
           [  30,   35,   36],
           [2000, 6000, 8000]])    
result=np.array([sss.zs(item) for item in a])

my_result=my_zs(a)
print(my_result)
# [[-1.22474487  0.          1.22474487]
#  [-1.3970014   0.50800051  0.88900089]
#  [-1.33630621  0.26726124  1.06904497]]
assert(np.allclose(result,my_result))
```

Answer (score 2):

the new zscore of scipy, available in the next release takes arbitrary array dimension

http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/changeset/6169